# How to inner join with multiple tables for 3NF Normalization in SQL

Tags: sql, inner-join

I am trying to create normalization 3 nf (normal form) in this database. However, when I execute the query, the table is empty. As you will see, this is my table and diagram.

Here is the relationship that we want to 3NF

***Torder->(Customer-Food-Carrier-Waiter)-(Ternary Relationship)-(Customer_id,Food_id,Carrier_id,Waiter_id)***

Here is my query

```
SELECT 
    Customers.ID AS CustomerID,
    Food.ID AS FoodID,
    Carrier.ID AS CarrierID,
    Waiter.ID AS WaiterID,
    tOrder.ID AS TORDERID
FROM
    tOrder
INNER JOIN
    Customers ON Customers.ID = tOrder.Customer_id
INNER JOIN
    Food ON Food.ID = tOrder.Food_id
INNER JOIN
    Carrier ON Carrier.ID = tOrder.Carrier_id
INNER JOIN
    Waiter ON Waiter.ID = tOrder.Waiter_id
ORDER BY tOrder.ID;
```

[image: Here is the output]

---

[image: Here is my table diagrams]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly, you have an issue where some of the tables are empty or the ids do not match.  You can use `LEFT JOIN` to keep all orders and see what is happening:

```
FROM tOrder o LEFT JOIN
     Customers c
     ON c.ID = o.Customer_id LEFT JOIN
     Food f
     ON f.ID = o.Food_id LEFT JOIN
     Carrier ca
     ON ca.ID = o.Carrier_id LEFT JOIN
     Waiter w
     ON w.ID = o.Waiter_id
```

If there are no matches, then the orders are still in the results, with `NULL` for the values in the table with no matches.

Note that this also introduces table aliases, so the query is easier to write and to read.